# Can't change the value of Float in Java

Tags: java, floating-point

Ok, I'm having this odd problem. When I try to change the value of a float, it won't change the value. This is how I am trying to change it:

```
static float float1ID;
public void void1() {
    if(boolean1) {
        float1ID = 56F;
    } else if(!boolean1) {
        float1ID = 0F;
    }
}
```

Full code(Changed variables, to keep it simple.):

```
static boolean diamond = false;
static boolean iron = false;
static boolean fuel = false;
static boolean gold = false;
static boolean redstone = false;
static boolean circuit = false;
static boolean danger = false;
static boolean valuable = false;
static boolean nether = false;
static boolean farm = false;
static boolean home = false;
static boolean dungeon = false;

static float diamondID;



public void BlockList(){
    if(diamond){
        diamondID = 56F;
    }else{
        diamondID = 0F;
    }



}
```

It just stays at 0. Could you help me?
Thanks.

Comment: What's the value of boolean1? How did you call void1()? We need more.

Comment: Also, there's no need to do `else if(!boolean1)`, just an `else` would work fine.

Comment: You seem to have a different definition of "full code" to the rest of us :-) (1) What is `Var`? (2) Where is `diamond` changed? (3) Where is the code that you use to verfiy diamonID is not changing? ... and so on. The idea is to provide a complete minimal sample that exhibits the problem but this "my precioussss" attitude about your code is hampering our ability to help. Not complaining, just pointing out it would be faster if you just showed us the real code.

Answer (score 6):

With your original code:

```
static float float1ID;
public void void1(){
    if(boolean1){
        float1 = 56F;
    }else if(!boolean1){
        float1 = 0F;
    }
}
```

It stays at zero because you're changing `float1`, *not* `float1ID`, although you've now edited the code to fix that, so I'll assume it was a typo.

---

The only other possibility is that `boolean1` is always false. Otherwise the value *would* change.

In addition:

```
if (boolean1) {
    float1ID = 56F;
} else if (!boolean1) {
    float1ID = 0F;
}
```

seems a little bizarre. Unless you have a different meaning of "boolean/binary" to me, the `if (!boolean1)` is totally unnecessary. You can just use:

```
if (boolean1){
    float1ID = 56F;
} else {
    float1ID = 0F;
}
```

---

And, since you state in a comment that you're sure you're changing the boolean, you need to debug the code. Change it temporarily to:

```
System.out.println ("DEBUG A, boolean is " + boolean1 +
    ", float is " + float1ID);
if (boolean1){
    System.out.println ("DEBUG B1");
    float1ID = 56F;
} else {
    System.out.println ("DEBUG B2");
    float1ID = 0F;
}
System.out.println ("DEBUG C, boolean is " + boolean1 +
    ", float is " + float1ID);
```

and see what comes out.

Comment: No, I am changing the boolean. I've verified that.

Comment: If you have verified that variable naming is not the problem, and you know you are changing the value of boolean1, then you might post more of your code. For example, can you show us how and where you declared boolean1?

Comment: Sure, This is the full code, I was just renaming the variables, to keep it simple.

 static boolean diamond = false;
 static boolean iron = false;
 static boolean fuel = false;
 static boolean gold = false;
 static boolean redstone = false;
 static boolean circuit = false;
 static boolean danger = false;
 static boolean valuable = false;
 static boolean nether = false;
 static boolean farm = false;
 static boolean home = false;
 static boolean dungeon = false;

 static float diamondID;

 public void BlockList(){
  if(Var.diamond){
   Var.diamondID = 56F;
  }else{
   Var.diamondID = 0F;
  } 
 }

Comment: @user1172622, see the update with the debug statements. If you won't post your original code, debugging suggestions is probably the best we can do. The possibilities range from buggy JVM (unlikely) to your actual code not being called, to your renaming causing more changes than you thought. In all those cases, the debug output should help.

Comment: With further investigation, it turns out its the void… I swapped out other functions, and it has the same effect, won't change boolean states, integer values, ect.

Comment: @user1172622, are you telling us that the _return type_ of the function is what was causing your problem? I don't think so...